# How to use intent in Frida

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, frida

I want to start a intent broadcast from Frida. The android implementation is like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
Foo foo = new Foo();
intent.putExtra("foo ", foo);
sendBroadcast(intent);﻿
```

How to I implement this in Frida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for referencing Java classes and for executing a constructor is clear. Using that scheme I a getting the following code.

```
const intentClass = Java.use("android.content.Intent");
const fooClass = Java.use("Foo"); // TODO: use fully qualified name of Foo
var intent = intentClass.$new();
intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
var foo = fooClass.$new();
intent.putExtra("foo ", foo);
```

For the last method `sendBroadcast(..)`you need an `android.content.Context` instance. How to get this depends on your app and what method you are hooking.

If you are hooking for example a method of an `Activity` you can simply use `this.sendBroadcast(intent);`.